# What are the steps to change of Search Module Database Storage drive?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, fast-search

I want to change Database Storage Drive of Search Module. Anybody knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To move your indexes without having to re-crawl content, try the following using stsadm.exe:

> On the query server:
>
> stsadm -o osearch -propagationlocation
>
> On the index server:
>
> stsadm -o osearch -indexlocation